# How do assignments like b(:,:i-1)=a(2:,:i-1) work?

Tags: fortran

I'm trying to make a submatrix b from a that contains coefficient for each first row entries of a.
But I don't understand first 2 lines under the loop.

Here is my code

```
   do i=1,p
        b(:,:i-1)=a(2:,:i-1)
        b(:,i:)=a(2:,i+1:)
        d=d+s*(a(1,i)*det(b,p-1))
        s=-s
   end do
```

Comment: Please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions.

Comment: I do not understand your question. You did not actually ask one. What is your question? Do you need to explain some existing code or do you have some problem with the code you wrote? What problems? Be specific! Show more code and error messages or the results! See [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

`a` is a `pxp`-matrix whereas `b` is a `(p-1)x(p-1)`-matrix.
In each loop iteration `i` the first two lines assign a submatrix of `a` into `b` by crossing out the first row and the `i`th column of `a`.

For example `a(2:,:i-1)` means:
take all elements from 2nd row until last row and from 1st column until `i-1`th column.

Furthermore, `b(:,:i-1)=a(2:,:i-1)` means: assign the submatrix of `a` into the first `1..i-1` columns of `b`.
Note that we didnt specify the rows because the first `:` means that we are using all rows of `b` aka the whole column.

---

Example: `p=3`

Take the matrices (`a` has explicit values whereas we assign to `b` s.t. I am only writing down the elements `bij = b_{i,j}`)

```
a = / 1 2 3 \
    | 4 5 6 |
    \ 7 8 9 /

b = / b11 b12 \
    \ b21 b22 /
```

For `i=1`:

```
a(2:,:i-1) = / \  ! special case: empty column-range 
             \ /
b(:,:i-1) = / \
            \ /
a(2:,i+1:) = / 5 6 \
             \ 8 9 /
b(:,i:) = / b11 b12 \
          \ b21 b22 /
```

For `i=2`:

```
a(2:,:i-1) = / 4 \ 
             \ 7 /
b(:,:i-1) = / b11 \
            \ b21 /
a(2:,i+1:) = / 6 \
             \ 9 /
b(:,i:) = / b12 \
          \ b22 /
```